# Some explanation about python code

Tags: python

I'm studying Python 3. Recently I've started to use HackerHank, and there I found a solution to a certain challenge that I had not completed. However, I didn't understand some of the lines of code.

This is the code:

```
import statistics;
n = int(input())
x = list(map(int, input().split()))
x = sorted(x);
median = statistics.median(x)
L = (i for i in x if i < median)
U = (i for i in x if i > median)
```

These are the two lines that are confusing me:

```
L = (i for i in x if i < median)
U = (i for i in x if i > median)
```

Comment: Should be easy to find in a Python tutorial:

Comment: There called _generator expressions_. If you google the name, some good articles should come up.

Comment: Pedro, haven't downvoted your question but I suggest you first try to tweak a little bit your question so it becomes a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that way people will be able to test your code and you'll definitely get more answers

Answer (score 0):

```
L = (i for i in x if i < median)
U = (i for i in x if i > median)
```

is code for checking if elements `i` of a list `x` are lower or higher than a median value

with `for i in x` the list is parsed,  `if i < median` `L` ( lower value ) is set to `i` or resp  `if i > median` `U`  ( upper value ) is set to `i`

also see [Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)